# How to add user data to Excel file?

Tags: java, python, excel, pandas, append

I have a ready-made file with ready-made sheets, I just need to add data there for 2 columns, please help

```
| Teachers       | Subjects       |
| -------------- | -------------- |
| TeachersName   | SubjectsName   |
| TeachersName   | SubjectsName   |
| TeachersName   | SubjectsName   |
| TeachersName   | SubjectsName   |

def teach_add():
df = pd.read_excel(open('bd1.xlsx','rb'),sheet_name='teachers')
print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
mas = []
num = 2
df['Teachers'] = mas
ind  = int(input("Enter index: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    num2 = num2.split(' ')
    mas.append(num2)
print(mas)
df.loc[ind]=[mas]
df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

Comment: what did you try? What module did you try? Did you search tutorials for this? You have to read file to memory with some module, add new data in memory, and save all data from memory back to fiel using the same module.

Comment: i used pandas, pls help me

Comment: Im edit this code

Comment: how about `df['Teachers'] = mas` (`mas` without `[ ]`) for all teachers. For single tearchers it can be easier to put every value directly in `for`-loop  `df[Teachers].iloc[i] = num2` But if you use one `input()` to get two values then you have to one string with two values which you have to convert to list with two strings. ie. `num2 = num2.split(' ')` or `teacher, subject = num2.split(' ')` and then `df["Teachers"].iloc[i] = teacher` df["Subjects"].iloc[i] = subject`.

Comment: don't you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Trceback") in question (not commentas text (ot screenshot). Thereare other useful information.

Comment: `input()` always gives string so you don't have to use `str()` in line `ind=str(input("Enter index: "))`. If you use numbers as indexes then you should rather convert it ot `int()` to later use it as index - `ind  = int(input("Enter index: "))`

Comment: you can show this code, I'm just Russian, and the column names will be in Russian. Therefore, I cannot write as you wrote

Comment: self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\CourseraNew1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3120, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\CourseraNew1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3768, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
 File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\CourseraNew1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",line 748,in sanitize_index"Length of values "
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (6)

Comment: I edit my cod...

Comment: read my previous comment - always put full error message (starting at word "Trceback") **in question, not in comment**. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: BTW: you should use `df['Teachers'] = mas` **AFTER** you get values, not **BEFORE**. You should use it INSTEAD OF `df.loc[ind]=[mas]` . But I don't have access to your data and I can't run your code so I can't confirm if it will work. You could create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy it and run it - to see problem and test ideas for solutions.

Comment: and you shouldn't remove `input("Enter teacher ...")` because now code makes no sense.

Comment: BTW: next time don't change code in question because now my old comments don't match to code. If you want to show new code then append it at the end of question. You can even add it with text `**EDIT:**`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have in file - but if you already have rows then fo single teacher and subject it could be much simpler

```
def teach_add():
    # read data from file
    df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')

    #print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
    
    # ask for data
    index  = int(input("Enter index: "))
    teacher = input("Enter teacher: ")
    subject = input("Enter subject: ")

    # add data to dataframe
    df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
    df['Subjects'][index] = subject

    # save data to file
    df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

And here minimal working code with some data in code - so everyone can simply copy it and run it to see how it works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'Class': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
            'Teachers':['', '', ''], 
            'Subjects':['', '', ''], 
    })

#print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
print(df)

index   = 1
teacher = 'Albert Einstein'
subject = 'Physics'

df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
df['Subjects'][index] = subject

index   = 2
teacher = 'Alfred Nobel'
subject = 'Chemistry'

df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
df['Subjects'][index] = subject

#print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
print(df)
```

Before

```
  Class Teachers Subjects
0     A                  
1     B                  
2     C
```

After

```
  Class         Teachers   Subjects
0     A                            
1     B  Albert Einstein    Physics
2     C     Alfred Nobel  Chemistry
```

---

And if you want to ask for more teachers then you should use `for`-loop. You could ask how many teachers you want to add

```
def teach_add():
    # read data from file
    df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')

    #print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
    
    # how many rows you have in dataframe
    teachers_number = int(input("How many teachers: "))

    # --- loop ---

    for _ in range(teachers_number):

        # ask for data
        index   = int(input("Enter index: "))
        teacher = input("Enter teacher: ")
        subject = input("Enter subject: ")

        # add data to dataframe
        df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
        df['Subjects'][index] = subject


    # --- after loop ---

    # save data to file
    df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

or you could get how many empty rows you have and fill all rows without asking for index.

```
def teach_add():
    # read data from file
    df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')

    #print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
    
    # how many rows you have in dataframe
    rows_number = len(df)

    # --- loop ---

    for index in range(rows_number):

        # ask for data
        teacher = input("Enter teacher: ")
        subject = input("Enter subject: ")

        # add data to dataframe
        df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
        df['Subjects'][index] = subject

    # --- after loop ---

    # save data to file
    df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

It may need also different code if you don't have rows in DataFarme and you have to append rows.

---

**EDIT:**

`pandas` was warning me that it works with copy of data and I had to use

```
df.loc[index, 'Teachers'] = teacher
df.loc[index, 'Subjects'] = subject
```

instead of

```
df['Teachers'][index] = teacher
df['Subjects'][index] = subject
```

I also had to use `read_excel(..., index=False)` and `to_excel(..., index=False)` to skip adding colum with indexes.

Comment: everything is cool, but the rest of the sheets in the file are gone

Comment: I don't have your file, I can't test it on your data, I has to guess how it can behave with your data, I only shows how I would do it. If you want better help then in question you should add link to example file.

Comment: i did it,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: if you needed some more changes in code then you can even describe it (in `Answers`) as solution for your problem.

Comment: BTW: I created some file for test and it was showing warning that it works on copy - and I had to use `df.loc[index, 'Teachers'] = teacher` and `df.loc[index, 'Subjects'] = subject` instead of `df['Teachers'][index] = teacher`, `df['Subjects'][index] = subject`

Comment: After saving, all sheets in the Excel file are deleted except for the one to which I wrote new data, how to fix it?

Comment: frankly I never work with Excel files because I always keep in CSV files. Maybe it needs to open file in `append` mode. See in documentation for [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) - one of example at the bottom of the page uses `ExcelWriter(...,  mode='a')` to append.